# Changing default location of my Spring Boot template throws 404

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, application.properties

When I have my index.html at the default location(/resource/templates/index.htm). Everything works fine. But when I Try to change the default location, It simply throws 404. Even after changing the `application.properties` .

Project Structure

[image]

Application.properties

```
server.port = 5000
spring.thymeleaf.cache = false
spring.thymeleaf.prefix = classpath:/Frontend/public/
```

Controller

```
    package iit.kent.cle;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class RouteController {

    @RequestMapping("/[^api]")
    public String index() {
        return "index" ;
    }

}
```

Comment: you should change spring.thymeleaf.prefix = classpath:/templates/Frontend/public/ . please try it.

Comment: yep. works. Now JS , CSS does load .

Comment: Cool, I created an answer about it, please I hope my answer marked as is useful   :)  xD . Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should update the prefix on root of your application.properties, the root is in *resources* so the classpath starts on this:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix = classpath:/templates/Frontend/public/
```